# Answers which are not quite answers, but still could be useful to stimulate learning.

Tags: discussion, comment, answers

Is there some way to treat faulty answers or ones which do not address the specific question, but which could be of merit. For instance something that is

1. related which could help the person creating the question, but too long for a comment
2. an answer which turns out to be faulty but could be helpful in solving similar questions?

Sometimes it would feel like a waste to just remove answers just because they don't really answer the specific question. Is there some way to "lift" them out or mark them as something else than an answer?

Comment: Related: [Is sometimes keeping wrong answer reasonable?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159/is-sometimes-keeping-wrong-answer-reasonable)

Comment: As for very long comments, consider if it's not possible to frame it in such a way that it becomes a Q&A pair -- this way you can ask the question (linking back to the original question) and answer it yourself, and then link that in the comments of the first question.

Comment: I agree completely, and this use to be common, but there's been a [disturbing trend](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22010/is-voting-on-questions-getting-harsher).  I chalk it up to trolling.